# Does guice-persist support the @Finder annotation

Tags: guice, guice-persist

Guice-persist was based on warp-persist which had the concept of finder methods.

http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/GuicePersist

was based on

http://code.google.com/p/warp-persist/

I can see that there is an annotation for @Finder in guice-persist similar to warp-persist but there is no documentation.

Comment: I have a similar question on the guice forums... http://groups.google.com/group/google-guice/browse_thread/thread/416c37c337ef0a04/e920ef54b3a1b502?lnk=gst&q=finder#e920ef54b3a1b502

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to add the finders to the `JpaPersistModule` when you create it:

```
Module persistModule = new JpaPersistModule(...)
    .addFinder(SomeFinder.class)
    .addFinder(OtherFinder.class);
```